Issue with sleep mode
As the title mentions I have an issue with sleep mode.every time my computer goes to sleep mode due to inactivity I can't open again the screen and I have to restart my computer .To be more accurate I turn on the screen and all I just get is a Gray color and nothing else.(sorry if my terms or English are not perfect.also note that I'm kinda amateur here so please tell me if you need any more detail).
Well thanks for the help.After some research the issue is cpu related as you mentioned in the comments.The only workaround i found is by installing extentions for the lock screen.more specifically this one seems to work for my issue :
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1414/unblank/

There is "sleep", where a process voluntarily surrenders the CPU for a time. There is "suspend" where the system saves itself to RAM and enters a low power state.  There is "hibernate", where the system saves itself to disk, and turns the computer off. "Suspend" requires a modern CPU, with controllable power states. "Hibernation" requires a RAM-sized, contiguous swap space.

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
